# How to write unit test for Kotlin delete by id method?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, kotlin

I have this method

```
  fun delete(id: Long) {
    NotFoundExceptionValidator(!dishOfTheDayEntityRepository.existsById(id), "dishOfTheDay not found")
    dishOfTheDayEntityRepository.deleteById(id)
}
```

NotFoundExceptionValidator this just checks if it's null then throws error

this is what I tried

```
    @ConcurrentExecution
internal class DishOfTheDayServiceTest {
    private val repo: DishOfTheDayEntityRepository = mockk()
    private val mapper: DishOfTheDayMapper = mockk()

    private val dishOfTheDayEntityService = DishOfTheDayService(repo, mapper)

    @Test
    fun `delete should work properly`() {
        //given
        val id: Long = 1;
        //when
        dishOfTheDayEntityService.delete(1)
        //then
        verify(exactly = 1) { repo.deleteById(1) }
    }
}
```

when i run it it throws this error

no answer found for: DishOfTheDayEntityRepository(#1).existsById(1)
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: DishOfTheDayEntityRepository(#1).existsById(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mock your mocks behaviour, i.e. you should explicitly specify what the `existsById()` and `deleteById()` methods return. For example for `existsById()` it should look like:

```
every { repo.existsById(id) } returns true
```

I suppose that the `deleteById()` method returns `Unit` so if you don't want to do it like above you can mock `DishOfTheDayEntityRepository` like:

```
private val repo: DishOfTheDayEntityRepository = mockk(relaxUnitFun = true)
```

Now you don't have to mock `Unit` returning methods of `DishOfTheDayEntityRepository`. You can find more about it [here](https://mockk.io/#mock-relaxed-for-functions-returning-unit).

Comment: thanks it worked yeah i forgot to do that _